# motivation for the direct limit

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules

I know just the very basics on Category Theory and that's why I'm going to ask a stupid question.

I'm trying to get an intuition for direct limits for my course on Commutative Algebra. All the books I considered so far state the definition, maybe the construction in some category and the universal property. But why is it an interesting or natural structure to study?

On nLab it is written that "the limit construction has a wealth of applications throughout category theory and mathematics in general." What kind of applications (of colimits) are those?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sums of topological spaces are direct limits (which are not commonly treated as such, but are handy in some proofs, e.g. taking quotients of them). They are an example of so-called final topologies (instead of the dual notion of initial topologies, which are used in products and subspaces).

Answer (score 2):

Given a prime $p$,  the [Prüfer $p$-group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group) is the direct limit of the cyclic groups of order a power of $p$.

If $\Omega$ is an infinite set, the [group of finitary permutations](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Finitary_permutation) on $\Omega$ is the direct limit of all groups of permutations on the finite subsets of $\Omega$.

Comment: I’d say that the algebraic clouse of a field of prime order $p$ is mereley *isomorphic* to a direct limit of all finite fields of order of a power of $p$ (or one could say, the direct limit is *an* algebraic closure). I really think one should stress this because due to the nontriviality of the absolute Galois group, the algebraic closure of a field does not exhibit any universal property (except of course when the base field was algebraically closed to begin with).

Comment: @k.stm, point taken with credit, thanks.

Comment: The claim about algebraic closures needs to be made more precise. While it is true that $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ is (isomorphic to) the direct limit of its finite subfields, that diagram cannot be constructed without first having an algebraic closure. The issue is, of course, the existence of automorphisms of field extensions – merely taking the category of finite fields of characteristic $p$ will not give you the right diagram.

Comment: Algebraic closure removed to avoid any confusion in the reader.

Comment: @ZhenLin Can’t one use some sort of choice to find a subdiagram of finite fields of characteristic $p$ that has all objects and is commuting?

Comment: For example, ${\mathbb F}_{p^{n!}}$ (at each step, construct the next one with the inclusion... then it is just an increasing union).

Answer (score 2):

Direct limit is generalisation of the notion of union of a family of sets. Two other examples:

- *Lazard's theorem* in commutative algebra asserts that a flat $R$-module is a direct limit of free $R$-modules.
- Germs of continuous function at a point $a$ of a topological space is defined as the direct limit of the system of pairs $(U,f)$, where $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $a$ and $f$ a continuous function on $U$.

Also the dual notion of inverse limit is used in the construction of $p$-adic numbers, more generally in the construction of rings equipped with an $I$ adic topoogy,  and in  the definition of pro-finite groups, especially useful in Galois theory of infinite field extensions.